# Mongo query to update field and modify the data currently in the column(s)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to write a Mongo update query that updates a specific column and revises it using the current data in that field. So instead of:

```
$set: {
  displayName: 'test'
}
```

I need to append something to the existing data like:

```
$set: {
  displayName: 'test' + displayName
}
```

But the above syntax doesn't work - I'm just looking for the syntax to simply update a column to it's current value + 'test'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way for referencing document fields in update operation. You should move execution to the client and iterate cursor with [forEach](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/):

```
db.collection.find({ /* your query here */}).forEach(function(doc) {
     db.collection.update({_id: doc._id}, {$set: {displayName: 'test' + doc.displayName}});
})
```